# Combine two identifiers in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, sequence, identifier

I am creating a database in postgreSQL

I have two tables, one containing details about a house and another for each room in the house. The house_id is set up using `house_id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY`

I want the room_id to be 1, 2, .. n for n rooms in the house. Which starts at 1 again for a new house_id.

This mean I have to combine these two identifiers somehow, and create a sequence for `room_id` which only counts upwards for a new `house_id`.

Is this possible in postgreSQL? Or should I settle for a `room_id integer` where I basically check the max `room_id for` each `house_id` and add one to it to form the
new `room_id`

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for an insert statement i.e. how to get the value of next room_id based on existing house_id and room_id in rooms table?

Comment: I would preferably add it as a contraint or function in the table, but an insert statement would work aswell.

Comment: Your approach looks fine for an insert to get max and add 1 based on house_id. Refer following fiddle as per this [approach](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=922e550492180aca00cade0dd4e421ed)

Comment: Thanks! I will the approach mentioned in your fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Only deal with insert operation. Since update can be update to any integer value. delete can also delete any value.
- I enforce the not null constraint. Otherwise we need to deal with null case.
- [**demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d81067a94ec36b9ecda272143911d423)
- all `raise notice` is for debugging.
- one special case, when table room have zero row, then assign room_id value to 1 and set the sequence nextval to 2.
- if house_id is new value then set the room_id to 1 and set the sequence nextval to 2.

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION restart_seq ()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    AS $$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'new.house_id: %', NEW.house_id;
    RAISE NOTICE 'all.house_id: %', (
        SELECT
            array_agg(house_id)
        FROM
            room);
    RAISE NOTICE 'new.house_id already exists: %', (
        SELECT
            NEW.house_id IN (
                SELECT
                    house_id
                FROM
                    room));
    IF (NEW.house_id IN (
        SELECT
            house_id
        FROM
            room)) IS FALSE THEN
        NEW.room_id = 1;
        ALTER SEQUENCE room_room_id_seq
            RESTART WITH 2;
        RAISE NOTICE 'currval(''room_room_id_seq''): %', currval('room_room_id_seq');
        RETURN new;
    END IF;
    IF (
        SELECT
            count(house_id)
        FROM
            room) = 0 THEN
        NEW.room_id = 1;
        ALTER SEQUENCE room_room_id_seq
            RESTART WITH 2;
        RETURN new;
    END IF;
    RETURN new;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I added this to trigger to my database, thanks a lot!